# Error when using multipart/form-data and setting specific content-Type in stoplight

Tags: multipartform-data, stoplight

I have an API where I have to pass both file and an object. The API is working properly in postman. Following image shows how I have done this in postman.
[image]

I am trying to do the same thing in stoplight. I have written the following code in yaml file.

```
content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          files:
            type: string
            format: binary
          data:
            type: object
      encoding:
        data:
          contentType: apllication/json
```

When I run the API in stoplight I get following error.
[image]

I have followed this link https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/. Anyone know how can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is about mocking your API via Stoplight. If yes, this looks like something that Stoplight mock doesn't support yet.

Also, you don't need to specify the `contentType` if you are using the default types. One potential issue I can see is that your `data` parameter is marked as `object` but doesn't have any properties defined.

Comment: Okk understood. I specify the contentType because I found something similar in the swagger. So I followed that to check if that's work or not. Like here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/